# Why is solution 1 to close my application slower than solution 2?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

This code takes about 2.5 seconds to close my application:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

However, the following solution takes less than half a second:

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

How does this big difference in time come about?

Comment: Did you make a benchmark-test to verifiy this? This is performing this task some millions of times...

Comment: To verify what? The time difference is very noticeable, I have tried both options several times without changing anything else in the code.

Comment: _Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are running. If the return statement is called in the application entry point, it causes an application to terminate only after all foreground threads have terminated.
--
If Exit is called from a try or catch block, the code in any finally block does not execute. If the return statement is used, the code in the finally block does execute.

If Exit is called when code in a constrained execution region (CER) is running, the CER will not complete execution. If the return statement is used, the CER completes execution._

Comment: A difference of 2 seconds sounds suspiciously like [the finalizer timeout](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233622-exploring-the-finalizers-timeout)... does your code have finalizers? (E.g., `~TypeName()`, formerly called "destructors".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without metrics, I'm going to take a swing at this. Per the documentation on Exit:

> Exit requires the caller to have permission to call unmanaged code.

I suspect that the overhead of executing unmanaged code is where you are losing the time.

[Exit Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: There are a few other reason in the doc, including reasons to not use it..

Comment: @TaW Agreed. I called out the big one in my mind, but the OP should examine the entire document.